# Send multiple requests to Flask API

Tags: mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I ran into this exception while I was working with Angular to show my Flask API REST data which is deployed on an nginx server:

```
{ "error": "(_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (2014, \"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now\") [SQL: 'SELECT ......" }
```

This exception is caused by this function that sends two requests at the same time to the database:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let url = this.baseUrl + `/items/${this.id}`;
    this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe((data : Array<any>)=> {
        this.ItemToEdit = data;
    });
    let url = this.baseUrl + '/products'
    this.httpClient.get(url);
}
```

I use SQLAlchemy in the API with Mysql database. I thought that If I add a pool connection it will be resolved but It didn't, I still get same exception:

```
engine = create_engine(connection_string, pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)
```

What exactly should I do to handle this ?
Is there anything else to set on the server side to make this function work without getting an exception ?

## EDIT:

**Is this an observable handling problem or it can be fixeb by using `Gunicorn` with nginx on server side ?**

Answer (score 0):

Using Gunicorn solved my problem.
I launch the application this way:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers=5 myapi:app
```

And I don't see the error anymore even with 3 `mysql` requests in `ngOnInit`